# Converting Python recursive code into VB.NET

Tags: python, vb.net, recursion

I wish to "translate" the following recursive Python code into a VB.NET Sudoku solver:

```
def solve():
    global grid
    for y in range (9) :
        for x in range (9) :
            if grid[y][x] == 0:
                for n in range (1,10):
                    if possible (y,x,n):
                        grid[y][x] = n 
                        solve()
                        grid[y][x] = 0
                return
    print (grid)
```

Sub possible(y,x,n) checks whether there are clashes with existing cells, and returns true / false.

I tried the following for Solve() in VB.NET but it doesn't work (returns zeroes in non-fixed cells on the top row only...).  Any thoughts?

```
Sub Solve()
    For y = 0 To 8 
        For x = 0 To 8 
            If Grid(y, x) = 0 Then
                For n = 1 To 9 
                    If Possible(y, x, n) Then 
                        Grid(y, x) = n 
                        Solve() 
                        Grid(y, x) = 0
                    End If
                Next n
                Return
            End If
        Next x
    Next y
End Sub
```

The full background is available here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM

Comment: Debug your code. If you don't know exactly what the code does at every step and exactly where and how the code behaves other than you expect then you shouldn't be posting here yet. If you do know that then you should be able to tell us.

Comment: would help to show your translation of `Grid` as well. `Dim Grid(9,9) As Integer`, I'm guessing? And what about `Possible`?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, Dim Grid(9,9) and Dim Possible(9,9,9) declared.